# Cassandra does not report that up and running when started

Tags: cassandra

I got an out put on my Windows command line when I execute the following .bat file

```
bin\cassandra.bat
```

and here's the out put that I'm getting on my command line

```
Drive already SUBSTed
Starting Cassandra Server
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8888
INFO - Sampling index for E:\myfirstapp\cassandra\data\system\LocationInfo-1-Dat
a.db
INFO - Replaying E:\myfirstapp\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-1267714669843.log
INFO - LocationInfo has reached its threshold; switching in a fresh Memtable
INFO - Enqueuing flush of Memtable(LocationInfo)@19173163
INFO - Sorting Memtable(LocationInfo)@19173163
INFO - Writing Memtable(LocationInfo)@19173163
INFO - Completed flushing E:\myfirstapp\cassandra\data\system\LocationInfo-2-Dat
a.db
INFO - Log replay complete
INFO - Saved Token found: 68001116758853706850435234194693732005
INFO - Starting up server gossip
_
```

after this nothing happens it just bleeping, I want to know what's the reason for this issue and how to go through it 
My system is Windows XP, Java 6

Thanks.

Comment: MMRUser -- can you enable DEBUG logging, restart, and repost the output as a response to this comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"bleeping?"

What are you expecting to see happen?

Edit: If you're not running with -f then it closes stdout and starts writing to the log file you specified in your configuration xml.

Comment: I'm expecting something like "server is now up and running" this doesn't mean anything and I don't know weather it is running.

Comment: Following this message, MMRUser should expect to see "INFO - Cassandra starting up..."

Answer (score 0):

"Drive already SUBSTed" is a Windows/DOS error message - the first thing you should see is "Starting Cassandra Server".

Google for "Drive already SUBSTed" to see why you are getting this - is there something unusual about the drive configuration you are using? http://zotline.com/shownote.zot/NoteNum/1884.html suggests that you are trying to assign a windows drive letter that's already assigned.